# Reduce the second order ODE for the motion of a simple pendulum with no air drag to first order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The second order ordinary differential equation for the motion of a simple pendulum with no air drag to first order is

$$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} +\frac{g}{L}\cdot\sin(\theta) = 0$$
where, $\theta$ is angle between string and vertical.

Here, the simple pendulum consists of mass $m$ swinging at the end of massless string of length $L$

I need to reduce the order of this equation by substituting

$p = \frac{d\theta}{dt}$ and then solve it in terms of $p$ and $\theta$

I am having trouble solving this because I am unable to eliminate $t$ from this since $\frac{d^2\theta}{dt} = \frac{dp}{dt}$ and still it depends on $t$

Comment: may be this can help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104626/solve-thetag-sin-theta-0?rq=1

Comment: @FaradayPathak thank you so much

Comment: Is this meant to be the substitution $p(θ)=\frac{dθ}{dt}$ so that $$\frac{dp}{dθ}=-\frac{g}{L}\frac{\sinθ}{p}?$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} +\frac{g}{L}\cdot\sin(\theta) = 0$$
$$2\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}\frac{d\theta}{dt} +2\frac{g}{L}\cdot\sin(\theta)\frac{d\theta}{dt} = 0$$
$$\left(\frac{d\theta}{dt}\right)^2-2\frac{g}{L}\cos(\theta)=\text{constant}$$
$$\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\pm\sqrt{2\frac{g}{L}\cos(\theta)+c_1}$$
$$t=\pm\int \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{2\frac{g}{L}\cos(\theta)+c_1}}+c_2$$
This is an elliptic integral of first kind http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html.
The inverse function $\theta(t)$ is a Jacobi elliptic function : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiEllipticFunctions.html

In general this function cannot be expressed with a finite number of elementary functions. Approximates can be obtained with numerical calculus of series or integrals.

Sorry i cannot understand why the same answer appears two times. I delete one of them.